# What is the right way to inject Spring Data repositories?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

Modern Spring recommendations (Spring 4.x onwards) recommend not using field injection (with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`), and instead preferring constructor arguments. Several discussions about this [here](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/), [here](https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/) and the [Spring Framework itself recommends constructor-based DI for mandatory dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-setter-injection).
In general I agree perfectly with the rationale, and in fact I haven't used any of the field injection mechanisms for years now.

What is bugging me however is the way we inject Spring Data Repositories. Of course these are mandatory dependencies, the service needs them to work. When one looks at the [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.web.pageables) one finds that the reference documentation itself is using `@Autowired` field injection all over the place, precisely what was recommended as bad practice in the Spring Framework documentation itself.

Of course, it is no problem to have repositories use constructor injection. I have been using this for quite some time. However, sometimes components and services need quite a number of repositories. A service might be interacting with 7 or 8 database tables, and they would need to be in the same transaction.

How does one go about this to have neat code? Using constructor arguments is the safer approach, but leads you to have a huge number of constructor arguments. Setter injection does not seem to fit, these are not optional dependencies. Field injection is supposed to be plain wrong (even though the Spring Data doc uses it).

Is there any other approach one could use? I was tempted to aggregate related repositories in a separate `@Component`, at least the service constructor gets only one argument with this constructor. It does help a bit, but makes it even harder to interact with a new table (the new repository would need to be added to the aggregate, and the service would need to call the getter for it).

How is it supposed to be done neatly without violating any safety recommendations and adhering to coding standards (few constructor arguments etc.)?